# Populate input fields depending on the user input

Tags: jquery, flask

This kind of question may has been asked before, but I've been flipping tables over this for days now and really hope someone can help. I´m deploying an application, where the user can select a specific topic. After the user has selected his topic, the corresponding data should be in displayed in the other input fields. The data is collected via neo4jDB and then passed via Flask to the .html file. The get_person method returns a list with all persons connected to the specific (selected) topic and these persons should then be displayed in the input field.
Here´s what i got so far.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,redirect,session, Response

class SearchForm(Form):
    autocomp=TextField('Insert a Topic',id='autocom')
    auto_ifxp=TextField('Person',id="person")

@application.route("/_autocomplete",methods=["GET"])
def autocomp():
    topic=request.form.getlist("autocom")
    topic=get_topic()
    return Response(json.dumps(topic),mimetype='application/json')

@application.route("/_autocomplete_p",methods=["GET"])
def autocom_ifx():
    topic=request.form.getlist("autocom")
    person=get_person(topic)
    return Response(json.dumps(person),mimetype='application/json')
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<label for="autocom">Insert</label><input id="autocom" name="autocom" type="text">
<label for="person">Insert</label><input id="person" name="autocom_p" type="text">
<script>
            $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/_autocomplete'
                }).done(function (data){
                    $('#autocom').autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 1

                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/_autocomplete_p'
                }).done(function (data){
                    $('#ifx_person').autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 0

                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ajax call is working properly and post autocom to respective url. Here the example for javascript change function

```
<script>
    $("#id_autocom").change(function () {
      var autocom = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '_/autocom/',
        data: {
          'autocom': autocom
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data) {
           //Fill data in html dom
            alert("Getting data from back-end");
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```